Systemd not respecting CPUQuota?
I'm trying to see what happens with setting a very restrictive CPU quota for the system slice (in real life I'd not set it to such a restrictive value, this is just an experiment):
[root@localhost system]# cd /usr/lib/systemd/system/
[root@localhost system]# cat system.slice
[Unit]
Description=System Slice
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Before=slices.target

[Slice]
CPUQuota=50%
AllowedCPUs=2-11
MemoryAccounting=true
MemoryMax=80%
ManagedOOMSwap=kill
ManagedOOMMemoryPressure=kill

Yet when I start stress-ng in this slice, it seems to take up more than this amount of CPU:
$ systemd-run --slice system.slice stress-ng [aggressive arguments]

In top I can see some of the stress-ng threads taking more than 50% CPU. This happens if I set the CPUQuota to lower values - stress-ng doesn't seem to be throttled at all.
How can I debug this, or are my expectations misaligned?

Expectation's misaligned; this is meant to divide CPU resources when there's more demand for CPU time than there is CPU; try running a stress-ng that should use all your CPU inside and one outside of that slice, at the same time.

@MarcusMüller can I ask if you have a source? Since this post I've found this, that seems to say otherwise - "Example: CPUQuota=20% ensures that the executed processes will never get more than 20% CPU time on one CPU." https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.resource-control.html#CPUQuota=
